# Out of date state when using useState

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple file uploader component that allows users to upload and delete files. These files are stored in an array.

```
const { useState, useEffect, useRef } = React;

interface IFile {
    fileName: string;
}

const App: React.FC = () => {
    const [files, setFiles] = useState<IFile[]>([]);

    const onUpload = (e) => {
        const newFile: IFile = {
            fileName: e.target.files[0].name
        };

        setFiles((s) => [...s, newFile]);
    }

    const onDelete = (fileName: string) => {
        console.log(files); // could files be out-of-date at this point
        const filesToKeep = files.filter((f) => f.fileName != fileName);
        setFiles(filesToKeep);
    }

    const renderFiles = () => {
        if (files.length > 0) {
            return files.map((f) => {
                return <div>{f.fileName}  <button onClick={() => onDelete(f.fileName)}>X</button></div>
            })
        }
    }

  return (
        <>
            <input type="file" onChange={onUpload} />
            {renderFiles()}
        </>
    )
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I know useState does updates asynchronously. This implementation works fine as is but my question is, with this current code, could `files` ever be out-of-date when the `onDelete` function runs?

Here's the  working example: https://codepen.io/zerodarkthirty/pen/dyYLgpL?editors=0011

Comment: As long as you don't use `useCallback` for your `onDelete` it should not be out-of-state, since the function will be recreated everytime `files` changes.

Comment: However, since you are already using `setState(fn)` you could also do it for the `onDelete`;

`setFiles(files => files.filter((f) => f.fileName != fileName));`

Answer (score 3):

Since `onDelete` function is re-created on every render and lexical scope of the onClick handler calling `onDelete` is also refreshed on every re-render your files array within `onDelete` will not be out of data at any point of time

However if you plan to do any optimization such as using `useCallback` for `onDelete` in future, it would cause issues.

To avoid such cases, its best to make use of callback approach to setFiles

```
 const onDelete = (fileName: string) => {
    setFiles(prev=> prev.filter((f) => f.fileName != fileName));
}
```